# Error while importing Hyper-V VM on windows server 2019 Hyper-V 10.0.17763.1

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v

Hyper-V encountered and error while loading the virtual machine configuration from . Import failed, import task failed to copy file from  to  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I have encountered this error and am unsure what to do? The VM nd its related files are not, according to what I can tell being used by any other process. Happy to provide more detail and your assistance is appreciated in advance.

Comment: You will need to run ProcMon during the import to identify the offending process. Probably a security product. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Thanks for this, ran procmon and could see Sophos our endpoint protection come up. Disabled but still seeing the error. Nothing of note comes up in procmon now, just mmc, svchost, etc...

Comment: Disabled but still seeing Sophos access the file? Sounds fairly straightforward.

Comment: No sorry if that was unclear, Not seeing Sophos at this point

Comment: So it turns out that you (@GregAskew) were correct. I couldn't see the Sophos process running in ProcMon, but when I downloaded Proc Explorer and pointed it to the file in question, I found that Sophos was associated with it. From that I was able to use the file. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: FYI most organizations don't experience this due to some file types need to be excluded. Usually proactively, sometimes as a result of an outage.